# how does xs in this function work?

Tags: haskell

I am reading Hutton's book, Programming in Haskell.
Here is a function:

```
pairs :: [a] -> [(a,a)]

pairs xs = zip xs (tail xs)
```

e.g.

> >pairs [1,2,3,4]
>
> >[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]  --result

Problem is **how to read this function** ? from left to right?

I am confused how "tail" leave 1 element and then combine it with next element using "zip"
Since "tail" suppose to get all remaining elements from the list right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I haven't read the book you mentioned, but I'll try to explain what I know.

You're right about the `tail` function returning everything except the first element of the list. Let's see how `zip` works,

```
zip [1, 2, 3, 4] [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

gives,

```
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
```

Now, consider the output we need from the input we have, observe the transformation required from input to output,

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] -> [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]
```

From the above application of `zip`, we can see the output we need can be obtained by calling `zip` with,

```
zip [1, 2, 3] [2, 3, 4]
```

Now, from the [docs on `zip` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:zip), we can see that if the two given lists are of unequal length, the extra items in the longer list are discarded. So, we'd get the same result with,

```
zip [1, 2, 3, 4] [2, 3, 4]
```

in which the last `4` in the first input list would be discarded and we get the result we want.

This can be written in a function as,

```
pairs xs = zip xs (tail xs)
```

If it is something else you are confused about, do let me know.

Comment: yeah, it's zip function that I was not clear about. Thinking of xs as an iterator is a mistake

Comment: @CodeFarmer no, it's not a mistake. But do imagine that this generator yields its values to a persistent storage object - a list. After 1, 2, 3 are generated, they do not vanish. They're still there. And when one more is requested, 4 is generated and is put into this storage. Later, when there are no more consumers, the storage gets garbage collected. `zip` gets two pointers into the same list - one at the list's head, and second pointer at the next element after the head. Then as `zip` goes along the two lists, two pointers get advanced one notch at a time each.

Answer (score 6):

`zip` takes 2 arguments. `tail` returns its argument with the first element removed, but does not modify its argument.Therefore `[1, 2, 3, 4]` gets `zip`ped with `[2, 3, 4]`.